# ASP.Net global error handler for all... but a few

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to implement a global error handler for my asp.net website.

I usually implement this in the global.asax by logging the error and redirecting to an error page.

So far so good, but in this case we have calls to asmx webservices from Jquery, and, sorry to say, Errors thrown in the asmx webservice are used in the calling Jquery.
So when errors are thrown from an asmx file, i want to log them and rethrow them

The only thing i could come up with is to check for the .asmx extension in the stacktrace, but was hoping for some other way (don't know why, but string checking just feels awkward)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out to be NOT an issue: we are calling the .asmx file from JQuery so the class has a [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] attribute.

and when you set that attribute, the exceptions that occur are NOT propagated to the normal errorhandling process.

So a new fact for me, which normally would be annoying, but in this case it is helpfull.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter out asmx on the basis of Request.Url. The Request property will be available in the global error handler in global.asax.

Comment: That's what i proposed, filtering the extension, but i was wondering if there was another way...